# TypeError: can't pickle generator objects for Non Generator methods

Tags: python-3.x, methods, generator, pickle, joblib

My error is similar to lot of questions posted, but none actually solved my problem.

So, I was trying to use joblib's Parallel & delayed for doing parallel processing, and the function I want to use it on, raises error when pickling. I face the following error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle generator objects
```

Now, the function defination is as follows:

```
def checkProcess(self, param_set, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, scores):
    t1 = dt.datetime.now()

    self.__wrapper__(**param_set)

    self.train_estimator(x_train, y_train)

    predictions = self.generate_predictions(x_test)

    score = self.generate_scores(predictions, y_test)

    key = self.generate_key_from_dictionary(param_set)

    scores[key] = score

    if self.verbose:
        print("Fitted Parameters {}. Total time {} seconds".format(list(param_set.items()),
                                                                                    (
                                                                                    dt.datetime.now() - t1).total_seconds()))
```

And, Since earlier the error was raised from inside **delayed** function in joblib, I tried manually pickling:

```
pickle.dumps(self.checkProcess)
```

which raised the same error. Then I tried inspecting weather the method is generator (Which clearly is not) using:

```
import inspect
print(inspect.isgeneratorfunction(self.checkProcess))
```

And it returns **False**, as expected.

Now, the class name is **CrossValidation** for which method **checkProcess** is bound to. I tried pickle dump using

```
pickle.dumps(CrossValidation.checkProcess)
```

and it worked perfectly, hence I tried same for delayed() call using:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=1)(delayed(CrossValidation.checkProcess, check_pickle=False)(param_set, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, scores) for param_set in param_combinations)
```

Then the positional argument *self* was missing, which raised to error as number of arguments aren't the same.

To overcome that, I manually sent *self* as parameter using:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=1)(delayed(CrossValidation.checkProcess, check_pickle=False)(self, param_set, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, scores) for param_set in param_combinations)
```

And, that brought me back to same error which I mentioned in start.

My one thought was that the function **self.generate_key_from_dictionary(param_set)** returns a tuple. Which might be infered as generator, and hence tried commenting those 2 statements, and re-run, but the issue still persist.

I hope the question is not duplicate, and any help would be grately appreciated, as Parallel raises a lot of issues no matter how I implement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After much digging into all variables present in class, referenced by

```
print(self.__dict__)
```

I realized that its 2 variables were generator objects, which was causing problem. It was custom **range()** function which takes floating steps which generated generator object.

This was really strange error, and now I replaced that with

```
np.arange(start, end, step)
```

and its working like a charm